# DirectX high GPU usage

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I just started writing an DirectX application and I'm already stuck.

Presenting an frame (at 60fps) causes relatively high GPU usage.
<s>1% on my GTX1080 and</s> ~25% on an Intel HD Graphics (GPU).

That is just presenting the frame, no draw calls, nothing.

The code i'm using is similar to  https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/tree/master/examples/directx11_example

Now the question: How can i optimize my code to use less gpu time?

Comment: 1% usage is nothing really. How did you measure GPU usage? That 25% figure just looks like a single CPU core running at full speed. Most likely happens because you are not actually limiting your frames to 60fps.

Comment: I measured with multiple tools, HWINFO64, ProcessExplorer, xPerf. YEs 1% is nothing, but this is 1% on an powerful graphics card. 25% are NOT CPU usage (One Core at full speed would be 6% on my System). I am limiting to 60fps

Comment: More than likely you aren't actually using even a fraction of that CPU load to draw. DirectX limits you to 3 queued presents, so most of that is just busy-waiting. You need a real drawing load to do any kind of meaningful timing here. That said, Intel HD Graphics is mostly using the CPU as there's only a little bit of fixed-function video hardware in their designs so it's going to use a lot of CPU compared to other GPU designs.

Comment: Note that over time Intel has added more and more dedicated hardware for graphics to improve performance so it really depends on which Intel part you are using. For Intel-specific optimization strategies, see [Intel HD Graphics Developers Guides](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hd-graphics-developers-guides)

Comment: On top on what has been said, gpu clock vary with load, when i do gpu profiling, i always have to keep an eye on clock speed or i am like "why this draw call take three times more than the last run in the exact same view". especially if your max speed without vsync is way higher than the refresh rate, then the driver knows it can saves energy without hurting performance once you are locked to the vsync.

Comment: Yes, i am aware of the gpu clock and the gpu clocks are at maximum for my measurements. Also there's no vsync, this is an windowed application. The cpu sits at ~0.1% usage